# Why does this python re only capture one digit?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python RE module to capture specific digits of strings like `'03'` in `' video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4 '`.

And what confused me is :

when I use `'.*\D+(\d+).*mp4'`, it succeed to capture both the two digits `03` ,
but when I use `'.*\D*(\d+).*mp4'`, it only captured the rear digit `3`.

I know python uses a greedy mode as default, which means trying to match as much text as possible. Considering this, I think `*` and `+` after the `\D` should behave samely. So where am I wrong? What leads to this difference? Can anyone help explain it?

BTW: I used online regex tester for python: https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: Just in case one needs a proper solution that will also find a match at the start of the string: `^(?:.*\D)?(\d+).*mp4`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What makes the difference is not the `\D+` but the first `.*`

Now in regex `.*` is greedy and tries to match as much as characters as possible as it can

So when you write

```
.*\D*(\d+).*mp4
```

The `.*` will match as much as it can. That is if we try to break it down, it would look like

```
video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
|
.*

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
 |
 .*
.....

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                      |
                      .* That is 0 is also matched by the .

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                      |
                      \D* Since the quantfier is zero or more, it matches nothing here without advancing to 3

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                       |
                      (\d+)

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                        |
                        .*

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                          |
                         mp4
```

Now when we use the `\D+`, the matching changes a bit, because the regex engine will be forced to match at least 1 non digit(`\D+`) before the digits (`(\d+)`). This will be consume the `p` which is the last non digit before the digits

That is

`.*` will try to match as much as it can till `p`, so that the `\D+` can match at least one non digit which is `p` and `\d+` will match you the `03` part

```
video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
|
.*

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
 |
 .*
.....

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                     |
                     \D+ The first non digit. Forced to match at least once.

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                      |
                      (\d+) 

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                       |
                      (\d+)

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                        |
                        .*

video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4
                          |
                         mp4
```

Comment: Very clear! And so fast helping! Thanks a lot for your vivid process description.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with \D*. The '+' is for one or more and '*' is for zero or more.

As you have used '.*' in starting it become greedy and takes till ' video [720P] [DHR] _sp0' where in '\D+' case it quits at ' video [720P] [DHR] _s' leaving 'p' for \D+

```
>>> import re
>>> a = " video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4 "
>>> p1 = re.compile('.*\D+(\d+).*mp4')
>>> p2 = re.compile('.*\D*(\d+).*mp4')
>>> re.findall(p1,a)
['03']
>>> re.findall(p2,a)
['3']
>>> a
' video [720P] [DHR] _sp03.mp4 '
>>> p3 = re.compile('(.*)(\D*)(\d+)(.*)mp4')
>>> re.findall(p3,a)
[(' video [720P] [DHR] _sp0', '', '3', '.')]
>>> p4 = re.compile('(.*)(\D+)(\d+)(.*)mp4')
>>> re.findall(p4,a)
[(' video [720P] [DHR] _s', 'p', '03', '.')]
```

Comment: This enlights me . Adding more brackets and using re.findall() function to show the correspondences really helps! Thanks for your answer.