# VHDL signal assignment delay and simulation confusion

Tags: vhdl

New to VHDL and trying to implement a small cache.

Part of my `cache.vhd`

```
entity cache is   

      Port (  clock  : in  STD_LOGIC;
              rw_sel  : in  STD_LOGIC;  --'1' to read from cache ,
                                                --'0' to write to cache
              ad_sel: in STD_LOGIC;     --'0' to send address,     '1' to send data
              data_in :in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);    
                                         --send data or address controled by ad_sel
                     ...      
        end cache;

        architecture Behavioral of cache is 
        ....
        signal block_addr_n : integer range 0 to 15;  
                            -- cache block address
        signal block_cell_addr_n: integer range 0 to 1;
                            -- byte-in-cache address
    begin 
    process(clock, init)
    begin
    case init is
        when '0' =>
            for i in 0 to 15 loop
                cache_memory(i)<="1111111111111111";
                tag_memory(i)<="11";
            end loop;
        when others =>null;
    end case;
    case ad_sel is
        when '0' => 
            address<=data_in(6 downto 0);
        when '1' => data_cpu_wr<=data_in;
        when others =>null;
    end case;
    block_addr_n  <= conv_integer(unsigned(address(4 downto 1)));
    block_cell_addr_n<=conv_integer(address(0));
    case rw_sel is
            ....
```

part of my testbench file :

```
 ....
      --Inputs
   signal clock : std_logic := '0';
   signal rw_sel : std_logic := '1';
   signal ad_sel : std_logic := '0';
   signal init: std_logic:='1';
   signal data_in : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  ....
 stim_proc: process
   begin    
         -- initialize  
        init<='0';         
        wait for 100 ns;   
        -- read address "0101111"(MSB cut), expecting miss
        cache_mem_data<="1100110011001100";
        ad_sel<='0';
        rw_sel<='1';
        data_in<="00101111";
        clock <= not clock;
        wait for 100 ns;
        -- write to address "0101111" but written in "0000000" which is default
        data_in<="10101010";
        ad_sel<='1';
        rw_sel<='0';
        clock<=not clock;
        wait for 100 ns;
        data_in<="00101111";
        ad_sel<='0';
        rw_sel<='1';
        clock<=not clock;
      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

And what I got in the ISim window is [image]

Why doesn't the `block_addr_n` and `block_cell_addr_n` be assigned in the second 100 ns since the signal `address` be assigned at that time directly? I think this is the reason that causes my program into unexpected results， since the cache block 0 is written while I just set address 0 as default but pass in the address "0101111" after the first 100 ns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sensitivity list does not contain all the signals that are used in the process, since the `address` is a signal (assigned in the same process, but that does not matter) but the signal is not in the sensitivity list of the process.  So the process is not reexecuted by the simulator when the value of `address` changes.  Process parts:

```
process(clock, init)
begin
    ...
    address<=data_in(6 downto 0);
    ...
    block_addr_n  <= conv_integer(unsigned(address(4 downto 1)));
    block_cell_addr_n<=conv_integer(address(0));
```

If you are using VHDL-2008, then you can make the sensitivity list automatically with `process (all)`, but I don't think Xilinx has implemented VHDL-2008 yet, so you must probably make the sensitivity list yourself by manually including all used signals in the sensitivity list.

Btw, consider making the processes either purely combinatorial (gates), or clocked (flip-flops or RAMs), so that combinatorial process should not have for example `clock` in the sensitivity list.

Comment: By adding 'address' signal I correct this problem. But I sm still confusing. You say 'does not matter' about the assignment of address, does it mean all the real signal assignment happen at the end of process? Besides, I have no idea to make this part of my cache project combinational or sequential. I design to use switches and buttons on Nexys 3 to implement this project. So is it combinational or sequential?

Comment: And the clock signal is used as a trig signal to send data in.

Comment: The `address` assign takes effect a delta delay after the process has been executed, and if other signals in the process depend on `address`, then the process must be reexecuted, thus the `address` must be in the sensitivity list to trigger the reexecution, as you experienced.  By combinatorial I consider gates only, thus where the output is based purely on the current input like a function, and by clocked/sequential I consider a process updating state like flip-flops or memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have a idea about what will happen in a process runtime .And I finally worked out my project. A million thanks.

Comment: @ArthurTian: If this answers you question, then please accept the answer by clicking the check mark, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).  This also applies to [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29191040/2352082) for a question you asked.  See more in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your actual problem might be a misunderstanding about how to write a clocked process.
The way your process is written now it will generate purely combinational logic and latches.
What you want here is registers, RAM and combinational logic.

A clocked process would be written like this:

```
process(clock, init) --A clocked process shall have only the clock and reset signal in the sensitivity list. This is correct.
begin
   if init = '0' then --"init" is used as a reset signal
      for i in 0 to 15 loop
         --This will reset the cache memory. It works, but
         --doing it this way prevents the synthesis tool from infering a RAM block.
         --To allow RAM inference you can write only one memory location per clock cycle.
         cache_memory(i)<="1111111111111111";
         tag_memory(i)<="11";
      end loop;
   elsif rising_edge( clock ) then
      case ad_sel is
         when '0' => 
            address<=data_in(6 downto 0);
         when '1' => data_cpu_wr<=data_in;
         when others =>null;
      end case;
      block_addr_n  <= conv_integer(unsigned(address(4 downto 1)));
      block_cell_addr_n<=conv_integer(address(0));
      case rw_sel is
      ...
   end if;
```

Note that this will not work straight away. There are issues in your testbench as well. For example, your init signal is low indefinitely.

You may also want to use "if" statements rather than "case" for simple conditions. Example:

```
if ad_sel='0' then
   address<=data_in(6 downto 0);
else
   data_cpu_wr<=data_in;
end if;
```